# Translation of "range" (as in age range)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Is there a simple translation of the English "range" as in the phrase "age range"? If not, how would "age range" best be translated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a simple trasnlation using *intervalo*; for example:

> *age range* translates to *intervalo de edad* o *intervalo de edades*.
>
> *page range* translates to  *intervalo de páginas*.

Here's the second meaning of [intervalo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=intervalo) (according to the DRAE):

> intervalo.
>
> (Del lat. intervallum).
>
> 2 . m. Conjunto de los valores que toma una magnitud entre dos límites dados. Intervalo de temperaturas, de energías, de frecuencias.

Sometimes *rango* is also used:

> *age range* translates to *rango de edad* o *rango de edades*.
>
> *page range* translates to  *rango de páginas*.

Here's the fifth meaning of [rango](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=rango):

> rango.
>
> (Del fr. rang, y este del franco *hrĭng, círculo, corro de gente).
>
> 5 . m. Estad. Amplitud de la variación de un fenómeno entre un límite menor y uno mayor claramente especificados.

Comment: I'd say that rango is used as a synonym of interval when you're talking about the variation of something between a max and a min because you made a statistical study about that or there is an observation of it (as the RAE definition says). So you could use "rango de edad" in a context like: "La encuesta ha determinado que el rango de edad ha cambiado". Another example could be "El rango de frecuencias de la ondas recibidas era muy extenso". But it's difficult that you're talking about the variation of the pages as "rango de páginas" (unless that there were a survey/study about that...).

Comment: @Javi: you're right. I'll update my answer soon. Thank you!